# When you type "hello, world" in Clojure REPL, why does it say 'nil'?

Tags: clojure

I typed this into Clojure REPL (using the enclojure Netbeans plugin):

```
user=> "hello, world"
"hello, world"
nil
```

What's the nil about?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Every function or macro call returns a value in Clojure, even things like `if` statements or looping constructs or toplevel function definitions or print statements, which in other languages are "statements".  There's no statement/expression dichotomy in Lisps; everything is an expression.

So `println` and friends print to standard-output as a side-effect and return `nil`, as do most functions which don't have anything useful to return.

But typing a literal string at the REPL should return the string itself, as in [digitalross'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140740/digitalross) post.

```
user> (println "hello world")
hello world
nil
user> "hello world"
"hello world"
user>
```

In the first case, the `hello world` line is what was printed to standard-output by `println`.  `nil` is the returned value of `println`.  In the second case, `"hello world"` is the returned value of `"hello world"` since a string evaluates to itself.  Nothing is printed to standard-output in this case.

(SLIME and some other REPL interfaces will helpfully color standard-output (the `hello world` line above) differently from the returned value of what you typed at the REPL (`nil` above), since it might be confusing otherwise.)

This is what you should see at a REPL.  What you posted must be an artifact of Enclojure.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you. I wonder if there's a problem with my installation of enclojure or whether this is, as you say, an expected artifact of enclojure. I also wonder what other "artifacts" I may encounter if I continue to use enclojure.

Answer (score 4):

#### Can't reproduce...

It doesn't do that for me on Clojure 1.0.0-

```
$ java -cp clo*.jar clojure.lang.Repl
Clojure 1.0.0-
user=> "hello, world"
"hello, world"
user=>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are some recent bugs related to interpreting the CRLF end of line sequence as two different expressions under windows. The return value of a string in clojure should be the string its self.

Answer (score 0):

i think it's the return value of your expression. It's the case in ruby with puts method.

Comment: The expression is a string literal, and the return value is the string.