# LightTable REPL returns nil instead function return value

Tags: clojure, lighttable

Why LightTable does not show the functions results instead it returns nil?

```
(defn greet
  ([] (greet "you"))
  ([name] (print "Hello" name))) #'user/greet

(greet) nil
(greet "World") nil
```

Comment: go to console by pressing ctrl+space and search for console
and check output there

Comment: Thank you, I chose toggle console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, that is not a LightTable issue, 'print' function returns nil.
You can see 
[When you type "hello, world" in Clojure REPL, why does it say 'nil'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416067/when-you-type-hello-world-in-clojure-repl-why-does-it-say-nil)